how to restart a tweenanimation?
I would like to reanimate a text every time this text, aka customtext is changed, or every time I push a button. Is there a function for that what I could call from the button?
Thanks!
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_value/flutter_reactive_value.dart';

var customtext = ReactiveValueNotifier<String>('from clear to blurred');

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
                  tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 10),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 15000),
                  builder: (_, value, __) {
                    return ImageFiltered(
                      imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
                        sigmaX: value,
                        sigmaY: value,
                      ),
                      child: Text('${customtext.reactiveValue(context)}',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      customtext.value = 'again';
                    },
                    child: Text('new value', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have found this animationcontroller https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html
but don't know what to add to vsync, also don't know if it would solve my problem or not.
edit:
I'm trying, I'm trying... :)
Now I'm getting this when I push the button: "LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@18499174' has not been initialized.
". My code looks like this now:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_value/flutter_reactive_value.dart';

var customtext = ReactiveValueNotifier<String>('from clear to blurred');

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                AnimationThingy(),
                OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      customtext.value = 'again';
                      _AnimationThingyState()._controller.reset();
                    },
                    child: Text('new value', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimationThingy extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimationThingy({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AnimationThingyState();
}

class _AnimationThingyState extends State<AnimationThingy> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 8),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      builder: (_, value, __) {
        return ImageFiltered(
          imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: value,
            sigmaY: value,
          ),
          child: Text('${customtext.reactiveValue(context)}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_value/flutter_reactive_value.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyPageWidget(),
    );
  }
}

final customtext = ReactiveValueNotifier<String>('from clear to blurred');

class MyPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPageWidget({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyPageWidget> createState() => _MyPageWidgetState();
}

class _MyPageWidgetState extends State<MyPageWidget> {
  final _random = Random();
  final _listStrings = <String>[
    'first',
    'second',
    'Third',
    'Fourth',
    'Fifth',
  ];

  void _onChange() {
    customtext.value = _listStrings[_random.nextInt(_listStrings.length)];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              AnimationThingy(text: customtext.reactiveValue(context)),
              OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: _onChange,
                  child:
                      const Text('new value', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimationThingy extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimationThingy({super.key, required this.text});
  final String text;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AnimationThingyState();
}

class _AnimationThingyState extends State<AnimationThingy>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 15000));
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 8).animate(_controller);
    _onAnimate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AnimationThingy oldWidget) {
    if (widget.text != oldWidget.text) {
      _onAnimate();
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  void _onAnimate() async {
    if (_controller.isDismissed) {
      await _controller.forward();
    } else {
      _controller.reset();
      await _controller.forward();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller.view,
      builder: (_, __) {
        return ImageFiltered(
          imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: _animation.value,
            sigmaY: _animation.value,
          ),
          child: Text(widget.text, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


Thank you very much! But I having the problem with this, that it shows the text without blurred for a second.

@MyName I didn't understand. Do you want the blur to last a few seconds?

Don’t mind my previous comment .. (:
So my problems are:
The first text doesn’t animate.
The animation should go just one direction, not back and forth.
If the button is pressed before the animation ends, the app will freeze.
